# Prove that $L_{2,1}$ of a matrix is sum of $L_2$ norm of column vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, matrix-norms

**Definition:** Norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{2,1}$ of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is defined by
$$\Vert A \Vert_{2,1} = \max\left\{\Vert Ax \Vert_1 :x \in \mathbb{R^n}, \Vert x \Vert_2 = 1\right\}$$

**Problem:** Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Prove that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{2,1}$ can also be calculate as
$$\Vert A \Vert_{2,1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\Vert A_i\Vert_2,$$
where $A_i$ are column vectors of $A$.

**My attempt:** Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Vert x \Vert_2=1$. Firstly, we have
$$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}\langle R_1,x\rangle\\ \ldots\\ \langle R_m,x\rangle \end{bmatrix},$$
where $R_i$ are rows vector of $A$. Therefore, we claim that
$$\Vert Ax \Vert_1 = \vert \langle R_1,x\rangle \vert + \ldots + \vert \langle R_m,x\rangle\vert.$$
Applying Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$\Vert Ax \Vert_1 \le  \Vert R_1\Vert_2\Vert x \Vert_2 + \ldots + \Vert R_m\Vert_2 \Vert x \Vert_2 = \Vert R_1\Vert_2 + \ldots + \Vert R_m \Vert_2.$$
It seem like the 2,1-norm is equal to 2-norm of row vectors, not column vectors. Anyone can show why my proof is wrong and hint the way to prove this to me?

Comment: Well, what you're trying to prove is false, so the proof can't be right. Regarding what's wrong: _How_do you conclude that $||A||=\sum||R_j||_2$ from the last inequality? The inequality shows that $||A||\le\sum||R_j||_2$, but no $\ge$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you hint me the way to solve this problem?

Comment: I've been thinking about it for a few minutes, no solution yet...

Answer (score 2):

I think the claim is wrong:

Let $A=I_n$ be the identity matrix. Then the maximum in $\max \{\|x\|_1 : \ \|x\|_2=1\}$ is attained at $x=(\frac1{\sqrt n}, \dots, \frac1{\sqrt n})$. Then $\|x\|_1=\|A\|_{2,1}=\sqrt n$.

But $\sum_{i=1}^n \|A_i\|_2=n$. (Here, it does not matter whether we take norms of columns or rows of $A$)

Comment: In this link on Wiki, they mention 2,1-norm like the problem above https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#.22Entrywise.22_matrix_norms. I feel so confuse when too little document talk about this. Can you hint me the way to solve this problem?

Comment: The $L_{2,1}$ norm in the wiki page is equal to $\sum_i \|A_i\|$ in your notation. It is *not* equal to the operator norm of $A$, which you used as definition.

Comment: @daw ??? The _definition_ of $||A||_{p,q}$ is the operator norm of $A$ as an operator from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_q$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes, ofc, but not on the wikipedia page that was linked in first comment.

Comment: The general expression for $||A||_{p,q}$ on that Wikipedia page can't be right; letting $p$ and $q$ tend to infinity it would imply that $||A||_{\infty,\infty}=\max_{j,k}|a_{j,k}|$, when in fact it's easy to see that $||A||_{\infty,\infty}=\max_j\sum_k|a_{j,k}|$, the max of the $\ell_1$ norm of the rows...

Comment: @daw Look again. Under "special cases" the only thing that's said about $||A||_{2,1}$ is that it's the sum of the norms of the columns. It doesn't say that's the definition. In fact about ten lines into the section "Matrix norms induced by vector norms" it says explicitly $||A||_{p,q}=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{||Ax||_q}{||x||_p}$.